# Marking persisted computed columns NOT NULL in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

It is possible in SQL Server 2005 to create a computed column that is both persisted and is defined as NOT NULL (cannot contain a null value). The 2nd attribute is of importance when using libraries like Linq2Sql if we want to avoid a lot of manual work to assure our code that the column 'always' has a value.

With straight SQL this is very simple:
`ALTER TABLE Sales ADD Total AS (Price + Taxes) PERSISTED NOT NULL`

When viewed in the design window of SQL Server Management studio this column is correctly shown as a computed column with no checkmark for 'allows nulls'. However I run into a problem creating new columns in the designer to match this pattern: The formula is entered in the Computed Column Specification -> (Formula) property, and the persisted property is specified by setting Is Persisted to Yes, but attempting to uncheck the 'allows nulls' on a new computed column results in a dialog stating "Property cannot be modified".

I need to cover a wide range of skill levels, and to do so I need to provide procedures for adding columns that even a novice can follow (which means the Management Studio designer window). Is there some secret in SQL Server Management Studio for creating a new computed column as NOT NULL in the designer, similar to say how CTRL+0 can be used to insert nulls into cells?

Comment: With at least SQL Server 2014, your code will work straight away.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may cheat this with `ISNULL(Price + Taxes, 0)` which uses the default value 0 for NULL computations.

Comment: I do _get_ that we need to manually assert an expression is `NOT NULL` even when SQL Server can't prove it (e.g. [even `COUNT(*)` can be `NULL` under very particular circumstances](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7088)) - but I don't like how `ISNULL` just sweeps unexpected `NULL` values under the rug when what we _really_ need is a "`NEVERNULL()`" assertion that will cause a runtime error if a `NULL` value is encountered - I'm really surprised that T-SQL is still this "unsafe" w.r.t. NULLs while modern languages (Rust, Swift) have solved this quite nicely.

Comment: @Dai - you can cheat with some invalid value, i.e.

```sql
DECLARE @bla TINYINT = NULL; SELECT ISNULL(@bla, -1);
```

Answer (score 14):

As Scoregraphic notes, you can do this with `ISNULL`.

I often use this for computed flags, e.g., in the `User` table, I have a `DeletedDate` to know when the account was deleted. I then create a computed non-nullable boolean column called `IsDeleted` (type bit) like this:

```
isnull(case when DeletedDate is null then 0 else 1 end, 0)
```

The important thing to note is that the ISNULL must be on the outermost part of the expression for the designer to realize it is a non-nullable computed column.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and looking at the treeview on the left it had indeed set the column up as not null, even though in the right pane designer the checkbox was not checked...

```
ALTER TABLE Sales ADD Total AS ISNULL(isnull(Price,0) + isnull(Taxes,0),0) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1682) nullability is determined by sqlserver based on the possible value of the computed expression. Since `Price` or `Taxes` is probably nullable, it cannot be sure that their sum is never null.

However, as @Richard suggests, using the `ISNULL` method avoids this. Declaring the column `NOT NULL` should however not be necessary as far as I have understood.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, but neither `Price` nor `Taxes` are nullable.