# Create non-NULL computed column for constant CHAR(1) in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, char, nullable, calculated-columns

In my database I have some computed columns to help ensure referential integrity constraints. I use computed columns and not default-value columns because LINQ2SQL, which is what I use, does not understand default values from the database.

My attempt is to use

```
CAST('C' as CHAR(1))
```

which is automatically converted to

```
(CONVERT([char](1),'C',0))
```

by SSMS. However, this results in a NULL-able CHAR(1) column type.

If I just use `'C'` or `ISNULL(NULL,'C')` (which does result in a non-NULL type) the column is picked up as a VARCHAR(?). And, if I combine the two to use `ISNULL(NULL,CONVERT([char](1),'C',0))`, I'm back to a NULL-able CHAR(1).

There are two reasons I want this:

1. The computed column will participate in a relation with a foreign CHAR(1) column.
2. A non-NULL CHAR(1) maps directly to the .NET Character type in LINQ2SQL.

---

**Update:**

It Works For Me with `ISNULL(CONVERT([char](1),'C',0),0)`, but I'm not really sure "why". If anything, it seems like `ISNULL(..,0)` would un-unifiy the type further.

I would be more than happy for an answer with a good explanation.

Comment: Seems to be lack-of-awesome in SSMS window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050007/marking-persisted-computed-columns-not-null-in-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In SQL Server string literals without an `N`prefix are always treated as being of `varchar(x)` where `x` is derived from the length of the string.

```
 +---------------+--------------+
| String Length |  Data Type   |
+---------------+--------------+
| 0             | varchar(1)   |
| 1-8000        | varchar(x)   |
| > 8000        | varchar(max) |
+---------------+--------------+
```

2) As documented in [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The Database Engine automatically determines the nullability of
>   computed columns based on the expressions used. The result of most
>   expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns
>   are present, ... An expression that is nullable can be turned into a
>   nonnullable one by specifying `ISNULL(check_expression, constant)`,
>   where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result.

3) The documentation for [`ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

> **Return Types** Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal
>   NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
>   replacement_value.

These three pieces of information explain all the behavior in your question.

Comment: They sure do! Thanks. For some reason I had it in my head that ISNULL unified across both arguments .. silly me, should have RTFM'ed.

Comment: @pst - `COALESCE` looks at all arguments and uses datatype precedence rules but `ISNULL` doesn't. `SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(3)),'ABCDEFG'),COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(3)),'ABCDEFG')`